# spring 2.5 which loading context twice

Tags: java, spring

How to stop   loading context twice  in spring 2.5 application?

In web.xml I having following configuration setting while loading spring based application, I m also using "CRON" scheduler to schedule the notification mail based on the "CRON" expression value, But notification triggering twice, but same case for simple trigger it is working fine.

```
     <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dummyProject</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
```

Please find the above setting in web.xml and let me know the solution ,if anybody knows

Comment: Maybe you need to show the cron schedule code as well?

Comment: <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="emailSchedulerService"/>
  
 <property name="cronExpression" value="0 15 * * * ? "/> 
  </bean>
   
  <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="jobDetails">
   <list>
    <ref bean="emailSchedulerService" />
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="triggers">
   <list>
          <ref bean="simpleTrigger" /> 
   <ref bean="cronTrigger" /> 
    
   </list>
  </property>
  
 </bean>

Comment: Above is the configuration code to set the cron trigger

Comment: Please don't add it as comment, modify your initial question. Also make sure that you aren't importing/loading the same configuration twice (i.e. don't let your `dummyProject-servlet.xml` import the `applicationContext.xml` else it will load and thus execute twice).